# Brand new bike, motor conversion, crank moves when the wheel moves

Tags: conversion

I have a brand new bike and I am installing a Skyhawk motor.

I installed the rear sprocket using a [pineapple hub](https://www.motorizedbicycle.ca/miscellaneous-parts/pineapple-sprocket-bushing-kit.html). I am not sure how this could have tightened anything unless it happened while reinstalling onto the bike,  maybe overtightened one of the nuts or something.

In any case, what can I try before having to save and then spend another $40.00 to get to the bike shop and back? I am on a pension and it took me almost 2 years to save enough money to buy this stuff. Can anyone help?

Comment: Whats the question?

Comment: I think what you are trying to say if your freewheel no longer works?

Comment: Use the Edit link to expand your question.  Consider adding a photo if it helps show the problem.  I've never heard of a pineapple bush, but the photo suggests it holds on the left side of the rear wheel by compression which produces friction onto the hub?   Or did you remove the cassette from the right side of the rear wheel and fit this bushing kit instead of the normal chain drive?

Comment: @user80207 We need some more info please, else the question will end up getting closed.

Answer (score 2):

This is usually caused by the back hub. There is preassure on the outer side of the driver(freewheel,cassette, cogs, etc;), so when the wheels moves, the driver moves and pushes the cranks, thus not doing the "freewheel" thing.

So you need to check if the nuts, cones and bearings, are grinding anywhere by taking it appart. And just because you are doing that, clean it good and regrease everything while you are it, just to be safe.

When putting back your wheel, check for movement on the nuts, sometimes on frames with small room to play they like to tight themselves up to give you a challenge.

Cheers

Edit:

As I can see from some pictures, you have to install a sprocket on the other side of the wheel. Check for spacing issues, washers, spacing issues on your freewheel and hub.